# Blow-up and tangent cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let 
$$ f\colon X \rightarrow Y$$
be a (possibly non-dominant) morphism of complex varieties which is birational with its image. Assume $f$ contracts a sub-variety $E$ of $X$ to a point $p$ of $Y$; i.e. $f^{-1}p=E$. Is it correct to say that we have a morphism
$$df\colon \mathbb{P}N_{E/X}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}T_pY$$
?? (where $N_{E/X}$ is the normal bundle of $E$ in $X$)

And the tangent space to $f(X)$ at $p$ is the span of the affine cone over the image of the previous map??

Example:
Take $X$ to be a smooth surface with a $-2$ curve $E$. Let $f$ be the blow down of $E$. Then $\mathbb{P}T_pY=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $df$ wants to be a degree $2$ embedding of $E$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. (And $df(E)$ spans all $\mathbb{P}^2$) (In this case $\mathbb{P}N_{E/X}=E$)

Comment: You are not telling us very much about $X$, $Y$ and $E$.  Are any of these smooth?  At any rate, I think the correct approach is to consider the induced morphism between the "deformation to the normal cones" of $E$ in $X$, respectively $\{p\}$ in $Y$.

Comment: Say $X$ is smooth. $Y$ really does not want to be smooth at $p$. An example: contract a $-2$ curve on a surface, then the image of $E$ should be a degree two curve in \mathbb{P}T_p Y

Comment: Namely: take $X$ to be a smooth surface with a -2 curve $E$. $Y$ is the blow-down. Then $\mathbb{P}T_p Y$ is a plane, the putative $df$ embeds $E$ as a degree 2 curve, and the image of $E$ span all $T_pY$. Is this a general phenomena?? also when $f$ is not dominant?? (but birational with its image)

Comment: I agree with Jason. I would first look at $N_{E/X} \to N_{p/Y} \hookrightarrow T_p Y$, and observe that this is dilation-equivariant. I guess your question is whether this can actually be projectivized? How about the map $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^1$, $z\mapsto z^3$, $p = 0$?

Comment: Allen, thank you for your comment. In the sequence you wrote $E$, seen as the zero section of $N_{E/X}$ is contracted to zero, which is pity. In your example, if you projectivize the tangent spaces you get a map between two points; and, to be pedantic, the affine cone over a point span all $T_0\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: have you had a look at 'Geometry of Algebraic Curves' ch.2 .  My copy is mia, but I think that they claim that the fiber of  f needs to be smooth for the statement you want.  In any event, they certainly discuss your set up.